# Game-engine question on hold because bug?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've come across a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107187/games-exported-from-blender-game-engine-will-not-play).

It asks about a bug in the game-engine and was therefore put on hold, since it

> should be reported to the official bug tracker.

Considering that the game engine won't be in 2.8 anymore, I guess nobody at the Blender Foundation cares anymore about solving these bugs.

**My question:**

Shall bug-concerning game-engine questions still be flagged and put on hold? In my opinion this will make it even more unlikely for those who ask, to find an answer.

Comment: "*In my opinion this will make it even more unlikely for those who ask, to find an answer*". I'll just add that regardless of the application component or its impending removal, the solution to all bugs (Blender or otherwise) is to *fix them*. Since most of us aren't developers and can't really fix them, having posts here make little sense, unless you are looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We (blender.stackexchange.com) do not take *any* bug questions. Does not matter if about the now removed BGE, or any other part of blender. Bug related questions have always been off topic.

Yes absolutely still close them with he bug reason. (top choice in the off-topic category)

> This question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender. These should be reported to the official bug tracker.

---

This particular question was about he UPBGE, so you could suggest the OP report the bug to [their tracker](https://github.com/UPBGE/blender/issues).

Comment: I assume that we would make some concessions if the question was clearly focused on asking about potential workarounds for the bug?

Answer (score 0):

[bge-community / Ketsji-Game-Engine](https://github.com/bge-community/Ketsji-Game-Engine)

[UPBGE / licuadora](https://github.com/UPBGE/blender)

You can ask here or report this in these two repositories, I recommend you read the basic use of github to report errors and they will always answer you, there are no delicacies like here usually there are and the answers are not quite accurate